# Cairo Dock still visible in Dash, after removal using Software Center

Tags: cairo-dock

How can I remove the Cairo Dock Icons in Dash even though I removed the app using Software Center? I removed Wireshark using the same method and Wireshark doesn't show up in Dash. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not removed the whole package yet. Its data is still in your computer. Remove all by running in the terminal:

```
   sudo apt-get-purge cairo-dock-core
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks I have never needed to use that command since I'm a months old Ubuntu noob. As an aside I don't see an option like AskUbuntu in StackExchange for Linux Mint, I am thinking of switching.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of the components with this command in Terminal:

`sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock cairo-dock-core cairo-dock-data libgldi-dev libgldi3`

You can also use Synaptic Package Manager

`sudo apt-get install synaptic -y`
`sudo synaptic`
to see the different components you have installed, just search for 
`cairo` 
or
 `cairo-dock`